# How to combine regular expressions and template literals in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, nsregularexpression, template-literals

I have read some answers to similar questions but I am still not sure how to do it in my case.

I am creating a search whole word function. Because the keyword is saved in an array so I need to pass it as a template literal within a loop.

I use \b to ensure nothing before the start of the word and the word may finish with "." or empty space so I put \s*.?
If my regular expression is wrong please help me fix it.

```
let text = 'I saw a afox foxa in the wood.no fox. The had red fur.';
let word = "fox"
const regex2 = new RegExp(`\b${word}\s*.?`)
console.log(text.search(regex3));
```

the result keep showing found nothing.
My syntax must be wrong in combining regular expression and template literal, please let me know how to fix it. thank you

Comment: You need to escape backslashes, just like you would in string literals that are enclosed with double or single quotes.

Comment: You want to use `String.raw`

Comment: String.raw works, thank you